# How update manager works in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, download, updates

I have installed ubuntu 13.10 few days ago. How does update manager works ? Does it require password to install only or both download and install ? or it does download fully/partly without authorisation and install upon authorisation ?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to post the answer here but it's provided with full details on the official website so I refer you (and possible future viewers) to [here] (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SoftwareUpdates) and avoid C&P.

Hope this help.